# Implementing method to interact with ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I want to connect the method `returnedConversion` so that it returns the result to the `ActionListener` after the user has selected which temp scale to convert to and from.  I realize that the code is a little disjointed to say the least, so please ignore all of the commented out areas (unless you can point out an area that I should pay attention to.

How do I connect that code from the method `returnedConversion` to the `ActionListener` so the code operates correctly?  Also, have I correctly converted the input from the `JTextField` box into a double and then appropriately converted it back to a `String` to pass it back to the 2nd `JTextField` box?

```
package temperatureConverter;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TempConverter extends JFrame {
    private JComboBox firstComboBox;
    private JComboBox secondComboBox;
    private JTextField initialTemp;
    private JTextField convertedTemp;
    private JButton convertButton;
    // private enum TempType { FAHRENHEIT, CELSIUS, KELVIN};
    private static final String[] tempType = { "Fahrenheit", "Celsius",
            "Kelvin" };
    public static final String theInitialTempType = null;
    public static final String theTempTypeToConvertTo = null;
    public static final String theChosenTemp = null;
    public static final String theNewTemp = null;

    public TempConverter() {
        super("Temperature Converter");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        firstComboBox = new JComboBox(tempType);
        firstComboBox.setMaximumRowCount(3);
        firstComboBox.addActionListener(null);
        add(firstComboBox);
        secondComboBox = new JComboBox(tempType);
        secondComboBox.setMaximumRowCount(3);
        secondComboBox.addActionListener(null);
        add(secondComboBox);
        initialTemp = new JTextField("", 10);
        initialTemp.addActionListener(null);
        add(initialTemp);
        convertedTemp = new JTextField("", 10);
        convertedTemp.addActionListener(null);
        add(convertedTemp);
        convertButton = new JButton("Convert");
        convertButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                String applyIt = returnedConversion(initialTemp.getText());
                System.out.println(applyIt);
//              convertedTemp.returnedConversion();
                // ???????????????????????????????????????????
            }
        });
        add(convertButton);
        // String theInitialTempType = (String) firstComboBox.getSelectedItem();
        // String theTempTypeToConvertTo = (String)
        // secondComboBox.getSelectedItem();
        // String theChosenTemp = initialTemp.getSelectedText();
        // String theNewTemp = convertedTemp.getSelectedText();
    }

    // public class textHandler implements ActionListener
    // {
    // public void itemStateChanged (ActionEvent event)
    // {
    // double convertedNumberForTheChosenTemp =
    // Double.parseDouble(theChosenTemp);
    // double convertedNumberForTheNewTemp = Double.parseDouble(theNewTemp);
    // String string1 = "";
    // String string2 = "";
    //
    // if ( theInitialTempType == tempType[0] && theTempTypeToConvertTo ==
    // tempType[1] )
    //
    // convertedNumberForTheNewTemp = (convertedNumberForTheChosenTemp - 32) * 5
    // / 9;
    // String result = String.valueOf(convertedNumberForTheNewTemp);
    // convertedTemp.getSelectedText();
    // }

    // @Override
    // public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    //
    // }
    // }
    public String returnedConversion(String toConvert) {
        double convertedNumberForTheChosenTemp = Double.parseDouble(theChosenTemp);
        double convertedNumberForTheNewTemp = Double.parseDouble(theNewTemp);

        if (theInitialTempType == tempType[0] && theTempTypeToConvertTo == tempType[1]) {
            convertedNumberForTheNewTemp = (convertedNumberForTheChosenTemp - 32) * 5 / 9;
            String result = String.valueOf(convertedNumberForTheNewTemp);
            return result;
        } else if (theInitialTempType == tempType[0] && theTempTypeToConvertTo == tempType[2]) {
            convertedNumberForTheChosenTemp = (convertedNumberForTheChosenTemp + 459.67) / 1.8;
            String result = String.valueOf(convertedNumberForTheNewTemp);
            return result;

        } else if (theInitialTempType == tempType[1] && theTempTypeToConvertTo == tempType[0]) {
            convertedNumberForTheChosenTemp = (convertedNumberForTheChosenTemp * 1.8) + 32;
            String result = String.valueOf(convertedNumberForTheNewTemp);
            return result;
        } else if (theInitialTempType == tempType[1] && theTempTypeToConvertTo == tempType[2]) {
            convertedNumberForTheChosenTemp = convertedNumberForTheChosenTemp + 273.15;
            String result = String.valueOf(convertedNumberForTheNewTemp);
            return result;
        } else if (theInitialTempType == tempType[2] && theTempTypeToConvertTo == tempType[0]) {
            convertedNumberForTheChosenTemp = (convertedNumberForTheChosenTemp * 1.8) - 459.67;
            String result = String.valueOf(convertedNumberForTheNewTemp);
            return result;
        } else if (theInitialTempType == tempType[2] && theTempTypeToConvertTo == tempType[1]) {
            convertedNumberForTheChosenTemp -= 273.15;
            String result = String.valueOf(convertedNumberForTheNewTemp);
            return result;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TempConverter tempTest = new TempConverter();
        tempTest.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tempTest.setSize(300, 200);
        tempTest.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't mean to create any extra work for the editers on the site, I did edit my code so it was all 4 spaces from the left and it said the draft was saved...

Comment: Where you want to send the result?

Comment: to the actionListener because thats where I think the it needs to go in order for the 2nd JTextField to display the converted value...is this right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a first step, read about ["Implementing Listeners for Commonly Handled Events"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/handling.html). This will give you a good idea of how to work with basic event handling in `Swing`

If I understand correctly, here's want you want to achieve:

- User chooses a conversion options using the `JComboBox` that you've provided.
- User enters the value in your first `JTextField` called `initialTemp`
- User presses `Convert` `JButton` and then you want to capture that event, covert the text in the first `JTextField` and display the converted result in the second `JTextField`.

So as the first step, you want to implement a method that does the conversion i.e. when the user presses the `Convert` button, this method will be called and it will take the value from the first `JTextField`, perform the conversion and update this as the text value in the second `JTextField`. You have a method called `public String returnedConversion(String toConvert)`, I would suggest some changes to this:

```
public void returnedConversion(String initialValue){
    //Step 1. Validate the input
    //Step 2. Convert the value. You write your own logic taking into account the initialValue
    //        and the JComboBox conversion options
    //Step 3. Set the text of the second JTextField to the converted value, using the method convertedTemp.setText(...)
}
```

Now you would want to call this method when the `Convert` `JButton` is called. So, as you've rightly done, you would want an `ActionListener` to be associated with it. Now what do you do over there? Well something like this:

```
convertButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        returnedConversion(initialTemp.getText());
    }
});
```

I hope this gives you the right pointers to help you out with your code.

Also as a final note, you might want to read about ["Threads and Swing"](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html) and ["Threading with Swing"](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml) to understand about how to start up your Swing Application

Comment: Yes I wholeheartedly agree that was a very well articulated response.  I'll be able to work throught the remainder of my problems now with a little more certainty.  Thank you Sujay.

Answer (score 2):

On line 49:

```
String applyIt = returnedConversion(toConvert);
```

Here you should pass a string to `returnedConversion` method, but you haven't declared and initialized `toConvert` variable as string.

On line 50:

```
convertedTemp.returnedConversion();
```

`convertedTemp` is of type JTextField. So you can't access undefined method `returnedConversion()` here. If you are trying to display the text in `convertedTemp` JTextField you should use `convertedTemp.setText(applyIt)`.

Comment: what do you mean "undefined method"?

Comment: In your code you only have defined returnedConversion(string) not returnedConversion().

Comment: Why does the method header for returnedConversion indicate in eclipse that I need to return a result of type string...isn't that what each of my retun statements in each of the blocks is doing?

Comment: Method returnedConversion returns String, so return statement should be the last statement of this method.

Comment: my code does not give me any errors now, thanks to your advice, but it is not displaying anything in the convertedTemp JTextField.  What am I not considering correctly?

Comment: You should check your convertedTemp method logic.